# Como retornar vector vacio en Java?

Tags: java

Tengo que retornar un vector vacio lo estoy haciendo de esta forma 
`return int[] prueba=new int[{}];` lo explico el otro dia el professor en classe y no me acuerdo por eso acudo a vuestra sabiduria.

Comment: `return new int[]{};` **Saludos!**

Comment: O bien `return new int[0];`, que hace exactamente lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes declarar variables en el retorno.
Para hacer lo que quieres es simple

```
return new int[1];
```

O

```
return new ArrayList<Integer>();
```